# Changing a certain index in a string to a preferred character

Tags: ada

When I try creating a subprogram that receives a string and a character and I for instance want to change the first index in the string to the character then return the result I'm not getting it to work...

This is how I tried doing it:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;           use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;   use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Test is

    function Change_Index_In_String(
        Str : in String;
        Char : in Character
    ) return String is
    begin
        Str(Str'First) := C

        return Str;
    end Change_Index_In_String

    Str : String(1..5);
    Char : Character;

begin
    Put("Type a string (5 characters): ");
    Get(String);
    Put("Type a character: ");
    Get(Character);

    Put("Your new string is: ");
    Put(Change_Index_In_String(Str, Char))

end Test;
```

How am I supposed to do this? I'm getting errors in my complier like this:

```
assignment to "in" mode parameter not allowed
 expected type "Standard.Character"
 found type "Standard.String"
```

I am aware on how to return the a certain index in a string as a character, like doing `return Str(Str'Last)` etc but what about changing a certain index and then returning it?

In the terminal if I type the string `Stack` and the character `W` it should return and print out `Wtack`

Answer (score 3):

One of the key design decisions to make is whether your subprogram is modifying state (a procedure), or returning a new value (a function).

If you want to modify an argument to a subprogram, then A) it needs to be marked `out` or `in out`, and B) it should probably be a procedure.

If you want to write a function, you should work on a copy of the input data, rather than trying to modify the argument passed into the function.

Consider the below example of both approaches in one program.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Test is

    function Change_First(s : in String; c : in Character) return String is
        s2 : String(s'range) := s;
    begin
        s2(s2'First) := c;
        return s2;
    end Change_First;

    procedure Sub_First(s : in out String; c : in Character) is
    begin
        s(s'First) := c;
    end Sub_First;

    s : String(1..5) := "Hello";

begin
    Put_line(Change_First(s, 'W'));

    Sub_First(s, 'Y');
    Put_Line(s);
end Test;
```

This gives us as output:

```
Wello
Yello
```

Comment: Ty for a solid response Chris! I understand the way of the procedure subprogram, but what I intially wondered about (I probably wasn't clear enough) is how you do this with a function. Is it really necessary to declare the variable S2 in your subprogram? Can't we just return S after we have set the first index to our preferred character?

Comment: If `s` is an `in` parameter, we _can't_ modify it. If it's an `out` or `in out` parameter, we _can_ modify it, but we _shouldn't_ because functions shouldn't modify their parameters. So we create `s2` (call it what you like), modify that, and return it.

Answer (score 2):

Much is undefined for your function. What should happen if the String is null ('Length = 0)? What should the bounds of the returned String be? One simple solution for one set of answers is

```
function F (S : in String; C : in Character) return String is
   (C & S (S'First + 1 .. S'Last) )
with Pre  => S'Length > 0 and S'First < Integer'Last,
     Post => (F'Result'First = 1 and
              F'Result'Length = S'Length) and then
             (F'Result (F'Result'First) = C and
              F'Result (F'Result'First + 1 .. F'Result'Last) = S (S'First + 1 .. S'Last) );
```